Apache Camel - Configuring endpoints using #Class or #Bean
I am new to Camel and trying to configure an sql endpoint's rowmapper property using #class (or #bean). Neither seems to work as it is always getting treated as a String
public String getDBRouteURI() {     
    String dbRouteURI = "sql:select * from " + importConfig.getImporttable() + " where PROCESSED_STATUS = 0?"
            + "outputType=SelectOne&" + "delay=10000&" + "rowMapperFactory=#bean:ROWFACTORY";
    return dbRouteURI;
}

and later
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    getCamelContext().getRegistry().bind("ROWFACTORY", new FileImportModelMapperFactory());
    from(
        toD(importUtils.getDBRouteURI()).           
        to("stream:out");
        
}

Neither does this work
public String getDBRouteURI() {     
    String dbRouteURI = "sql:select * from " + importConfig.getImporttable() + " where PROCESSED_STATUS = 0?"
            + "outputType=SelectOne&" + "delay=10000&" + "rowMapperFactory=#class:<className>";
    return dbRouteURI;

This is the exception stacktrace
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value #bean:ROWFACTORY converted to org.apache.camel.component.sql.RowMapperFactory cannot be null
at org.apache.camel.support.CamelContextHelper.mandatoryConvertTo(CamelContextHelper.java:178)
at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent.getAndRemoveParameter(DefaultComponent.java:507)
On debugging through the code the entire "#bean:ROWFACTORY" is being passed as a  String. I am referring to the documentation here - https://camel.apache.org/manual/faq/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html

Just a quick note. Debugging through camel, found that its calling getAndRemoveParameter() in org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent class where ideally it should have called the getAndRemoveOrResolveReferenceParameter() which resolves reference parameters.

Thanks for spotting this. I created a JIRA ticket so this can be fixed in future Camel release
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-21406
